# How to detect std::reference_wrapper in C++ at compile time

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, c++14, reference-wrapper

Lets say we have some variadic template and need to treat `std::reference_wrapper` parameters differently.
How can we achieve that?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: In what way do you want to treat them differently?  Print `os << "chicken"` when you print them, while using `os << t` on other types?  Treat `reference_wrapper<T>&&` as `T&` while calling `.get()` on them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can make a trait to tell if a type is `reference_wrapper`

```
template<typename T>
struct is_reference_wrapper : false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_reference_wrapper<reference_wrapper<T>> : true_type{};
```

Then you can use it to disambiguate:

```
template<typename T>
void do_stuff(T&& t, false_type)
{
    cout << "Normal: " << t << endl;
}

template<typename T>
void do_stuff(T&& ref, true_type)
{
    cout << "Ref: " << ref.get() << endl;
}

template<typename... Ts>
void foo(Ts&&... ts)
{
    [[maybe_unused]] int arr[] = {
        (do_stuff(forward<Ts>(ts), is_reference_wrapper<decay_t<Ts>>{}), 0)...
    };
}
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/KAE6nIJtnTSMSyks)