# clang not recognizing pointers from references from objects?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-templates

I'm trying to write a function that would work on a container of object, references, and pointer as well.
Can't figure out how to do it, given that clang does not returns true when using `std::is_reference_v`.

```
// Returns the centroid of a container of `Locatable` objects.
template<typename ContainerType>
std::array<double, 3> centroid(const ContainerType & container)
{
    if (container.empty())
        return {0, 0, 0};

    std::array<double, 3> cumsum{0.0, 0.0, 0.0};

    for (const auto & element : container)
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_reference_v<typename ContainerType::value_type>)
        {
            // If the element is a pointer, use .get() to access members.
            cumsum[0] += element.get().getX();
            cumsum[1] += element.get().getY();
            cumsum[2] += element.get().getZ();
        }
        else if constexpr (std::is_pointer_v<typename ContainerType::value_type>)
        {
            // If the element is a pointer, use -> to access members.
            cumsum[0] += element->getX();
            cumsum[1] += element->getY();
            cumsum[2] += element->getZ();
        }
        else
        {
            // If it's not a pointer, assume it's a regular object and access members directly.
            cumsum[0] += element.getX();
            cumsum[1] += element.getY();
            cumsum[2] += element.getZ();
        }
    }


    double f = 1.0 / container.size();
    cumsum[0] *= f;
    cumsum[1] *= f;
    cumsum[2] *= f;
    return cumsum;
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<Particle> vector_of_particles(5);
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Particle>> vector_of_references;
    std::array<Particle *, 5> array_of_pointers;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        vector_of_particles[i].setPosition({0.0, 0.0, i});
        vector_of_references.push_back(vector_of_particles[i]);
        array_of_pointers[i] = &array_of_particles[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Got this error:

```
error: no member named 'getX' in 'std::reference_wrapper<Particle>'
            cumsum[0] += element.getX();
```

So to me it looks like `if constexpr (std::is_reference_v<typename ContainerType::value_type>)` didn't work

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `std::is_reference_v` returns `true` on a reference, not on `std::reference_wrapper`.

Comment: Why type are you passing for ContainerType and how does it look?

Comment: FYI https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40430692/how-to-detect-stdreference-wrapper-in-c-at-compile-time

Comment: @Yksisarvinen yes, I guess. Any idea how to deal with that?

Comment: @kiner_shah just edited my question to show the main function

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it.

```
template<typename T>
struct is_reference_wrapper : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_reference_wrapper<std::reference_wrapper<T>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_reference_wrapper<std::reference_wrapper<T const>> : std::true_type {};

template< class T >
inline constexpr bool is_reference_wrapper_v = is_reference_wrapper<T>::value;

static_assert(
       ! is_reference_wrapper_v<Particle>
    && ! is_reference_wrapper_v<Particle *>
    && ! is_reference_wrapper_v<Particle &>
    &&   is_reference_wrapper_v<std::reference_wrapper<Particle>>
    &&   is_reference_wrapper_v<std::reference_wrapper<Particle const>>
);


template <typename T>
double getX(const T & element)
{
    if constexpr (is_reference_wrapper_v<T>)
        return element.get().getX();

    else if constexpr (std::is_pointer_v<T>)
        return element->getX();

    else
        return element.getX();
}


// Returns the centroid of a container of `Locatable` objects.
template<typename ContainerType>
std::array<double, 3> centroid(const ContainerType & container)
{
    if (container.empty())
        return {0, 0, 0};

    std::array<double, 3> cumsum{0.0, 0.0, 0.0};

    for (const auto & element : container)
    {
        cumsum[0] += getX(element);
        cumsum[1] += getY(element);
        cumsum[2] += getZ(element);
    }

    double f = 1.0 / container.size();
    cumsum[0] *= f;
    cumsum[1] *= f;
    cumsum[2] *= f;
    return cumsum;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This specialization `is_reference_wrapper<std::reference_wrapper<T const>>` can be removed.